# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Physics's [third moderator election](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: ACuriousMind] [image: rob]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5609110007447552/0).

Comment: Congrats to the new mods and may the force be with them!

Answer (score 16):

Congratulations to both new moderators! You'll both be a fabulous addition to the moderator team. Thank you so much for volunteering.

[image]

Comment: tsk, tsk Rhodium has symbol Rh not R and no idea why G for Beryllium...

Comment: @Ramanujan, sorry to disappoint =)

Comment: @Ramanujan You used this picture too, and that was my comment for you...

Comment: @Mithoron sorry:(

Answer (score 10):

My sincere congratulations to ACM and rob and I second heather's thank you for volunteering your time.

Answer (score 10):

As Jim, the High King, I officially recognize your meritorious service to the Jimdom. Furthermore, in light of the training, popular approval, and special services rendered to the King (specifically, stepping up to do the job that I really didn't want to have to do) I bestow on you the highest honours that I can.

---

As of this day, I dub thee **Sir rob** and **Sir** [*insert name here*], **Knights Moderatus**; members of the Court of Jimelot; with all the lands and dues afforded this rank.

Rise and never forget the oaths you have sworn this day, defenders of PSE.

Comment: Always a nice thing when the grand claims of the deluded coincide with reality.  Also your dinner invitation is still open.

Comment: adapting my delusions to acknowledge reality from time to time makes it easier to maintain said delusions in the long run. :-P